# setting up nginx X-Accel-Mapping for rails secure static content delivery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am trying to serve static contents via nginx & rails using `X-Accel-Redirect`. My actual static content directory located at rails root folder like this

```
  - "rails_root\books\sources\:book_id\remaining_path".
```

only the `rails_root\books\sources` is constant, remaining part always changing. ex

```
  -app\books\sources\111\oep\cover.html
  -app\books\sources\111\oep\images\xx.png
```

i tried setting up the nginx using the following configuration

```
    location ~ /readbook/*./.* {
      internal;
      alias /home/vooodoo/work/reader/books/sources/$1/$2;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_redirect    off;

      proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

       proxy_set_header  X-Sendfile-Type   X-Accel-Redirect;
      proxy_set_header  X-Accel-Mapping   /readbook/=/home/vooodoo/work/reader/books/sources/;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
    }
```

it successfully detects the request and passing it to the rails. on rails am doing

```
 class ReaderController < ApplicationController
        def resource
           send_file "#{Rails.root}/books/sources/"+ params[:id] + "/" + params[:resource] + "." + params[:format]
        end
 end
```

It returns the file info back to nginx, but seems rails doesnt understand the  X-Accel-Mapping of my config. so when nginx trying to read the file,  this error happens

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/home/voodoo/work/reader/books/sources/229/OPS/cover.xml"):

I strongly believe this is due to the `incorrect  X-Accel-Mapping in nginx`. But cant figure out what. can someone help me out. I am struck with this for last few hours.

Comment: were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `/readbook=/...` should be `...=/readbook/`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `X-Accel-Mapping` configuration is wrong, try this:

```
location ~ /readbook/*./.* {
  internal
  alias /home/vooodoo/work/reader/books/sources/$1/$2;
}

location / {
  ...
  proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;
  proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /home/vooodoo/work/reader/books/sources/=/readbook/;
  ...
}
```